# Solution verification: Partials of $f(x,y) = y/x, x \neq 0$ at $(0,0)$

Tags: limits, derivatives, solution-verification, partial-derivative

This is a question from Chapter 2 of *Vector Calculus Study Guide Solutions Manual (Karen Pao, Frederick Soon)*.

Let $$f(x,y) =\begin{cases} y/x, & x\neq 0 \\ 0 & x = 0.  \end{cases}$$ at $(0,0)$ Compute $f_x(0,0)$ and $f_y(0,0)$ if they exist.

I used the limit definition and I obtained: $$f_x(0,0) = \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(h,0) - f(0,0)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{0/h - 0}{h}= 0 $$ and $$f_y(0,0) = \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(0,h) - f(0,0)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{0-0}{h} = 0 .$$

However the given answer is that $f_x$ does not exist and $f_y = 0$. Can someone please let me know how my calculation for $f_x(0,0)$ is wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. Can you please expand on your comment? I think that $f(h,0) = 0/h = 0$ for $h \neq 0$. And so when I fully evaluate the fraction before taking the limit, it is $\lim_{h \to 0} 0 = 0$. Thank you!

Comment: Your calculation is correct.